# IOS Xcode Storyboard: Inserting a view behind already placed views

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a view controller with views already laid out. I need to put an UIImageView behind the views in storyboard without having to move the entire layout around. Is this possible?

Comment: did you get the answer?

Answer (score 6):

Drag the new uiimageview to the top of the list on the sidebar. That should put it behind the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a little button to open another pane in the bottom left of Interface Builder. You should be able to find your view controller and adjust the layering of views or anything else on the View Controller. Best of luck!